# Evolution of the virial ratio $-K/U$ in $N$-body simulation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, galaxies, virial-theorem

I have run an 2D $N$-body sim to simulate the cold collapse of a galaxy.

Initial conditions: $N=500$, all velocities=0, positions generated randomly within a circle of radius $R$.

The system is initially not in virial equilibrium, but apparently settles into a virial equilibrium after a period time which is in agreement with the theoretical value of the half-mass relaxation time.

I've generated graph below showing the evolution of the virial ratio (i.e, $-K/U$) in time:

[image]

The apparent fluctations are due to the lack of precision in the measurement of energy.

How can we explain the above graph?

Specifically:

1. Why does the system settle into a virial equilibrium?
2. Why does the virial ratio first increase and then decrease before reach the equilibrium value 0.5?
3. Does the system remain in virial equilibrium forever? The evaporation time of a galaxy is of the order of 100 crossing times. If we wait until this time, how will the graph change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Systems that are capable of reaching equilibrium will do so if given enough time. This is a curious question; I guess you mean what is the mechanism by which gravitational potential energy and kinetic energy are redistributed? The answer to that is mainly two-body gravitational interactions
2. You started your system way out of equilibrium. What happens is that it collapses, gives lots of kinetic energy to the particles and "overshoots" the equilibrium (a bit like a lightly damped suspension spring). After that it returns towards equilibrium, though looks like it does a further mild subvirial expansion before settling down. I would guess you would find that the timescale for this oscillatory behaviour is the "crossing time" (roughly the freefall timescale in this case), although it settles into an equilibrium suspiciously quickly - for 500 particles one expects a relaxation time of $\sim 10$ crossing times (NB very unrealistic for a galaxy).
3. What do you mean by "the system"? If you mean the remaining bound component then yes it should stay in equilibrium and roughly at constant total energy (since the particles that evaporate have an energy of $\sim 0$). But maybe what you are asking about is gravothermal collapse.
   Since the total energy is some fixed fraction of $M^2/R$, then as mass evaporates, the radius must decrease as $M^{-2}$ and the density goes up as $M^5$. I would think that the continual contraction makes the bound part slightly subvirial, but then after 10-20 relaxation times you will end up with some numerical catastrophe at the centre of the simulation as the density heads towards infinity.

Answer (score 1):

1. The problem is the algorithm you're using for generating initial conditions. Clearly it does not guarantee virial equilibrium, so your simulation starts far from this point.
2. However, as time goes by the system relaxes (through two-body interactions) until it reaches equilibrium
3. If you consider only particles that are still bound, the system will redistribute its energy such that virial eq. is preserved. Actually, it is very likely this is happening already during the time window you're looking at